# How to use restangular with promise pattern in angular service

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, restangular

I have a service with rest angular with following structure

```
function countrySvc(restangular) {
    restangular.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {

        if (operation === 'getList') {
            var newResponse = response.data;

            return newResponse;
        }
        return response;
    });
    var baseCountry = restangular.all('country');


    this.countries = function() {

        baseCountry.getList();

    };
}
```

also a controller

```
function countryCtrl(scope, countrySvc) {


    scope.countries = countrySvc.countries();

}
```

but when i access the countries from controller, the result is empty with a successful request with data, my question is how a can extract the data from response with proper promise pattern, ie( i need  array of countries when i access scope.countries)

Answer (score 8):

You need to resolve promise...

There are two ways to do it...

**1) Using `$object`**

just add `.$object` to end of promise so once request is done it resolves promise...

```
scope.countries = countrySvc.countries().$object;
```

**2) Using `then`**

if you need to do some stuff after promise is resolved pick this option, once request is done callback function in `then` will be fired

```
scope.countries = countrySvc.countries().then(function (response){
    // DO SOMETHING IF YOU NEED BEFORE SET OBJECT
    scope.countries = response;
    // DO SOMETHING IF YOU NEED AFTER SET OBJECT
});
```